# How to get SMS history with Esendex API?

Tags: api, sms, history

I'm using Esendex API to sent multiple SMS. Besides, I would like to get all sent SMS (maybe in a certain range), exactly like data from https://www.esendex.com/echo/a/{ACCOUNT_REF}/Sent.[image]

I've seen that there is "Push Notifications", in order to send notifications to a web server ; but is there a simplier way to get all sent SMS, something like https://api.esendex.com/v1.0/history ?

Comment: I found what I searched : https://api.esendex.com/v1.0/messageheaders (https://developers.esendex.com/api-reference#messageheader)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct you'd need to use either https://developers.esendex.com/api-reference#messageheader to get the individual messages or https://developers.esendex.com/api-reference#messagebatch if you send in bulk to get the batch data back.

If you need anymore help drop us a line at support@esendex.com and we're happy to assist.

Thank,

Catherine,

Esendex Customer Support Manager